# Hard floor function problem

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor $ denote the floor of $x$. Supose $m\in \mathbb{N}$, and that $t$ is a positive irrational number. Put $n=\left \lfloor{mt}\right \rfloor$. Prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^{m} \left \lfloor{kt}\right \rfloor +\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left \lfloor{\frac{k}{t}}\right \rfloor= mn$$

Comment: I see 3 votes to close, and zero supporting reasons. Anyone care to try to convince me that this question should be closed?

Comment: It looks like a fairly non-trivial problem; I’d certainly be interested in seeing a solution, if I don’t find one myself.

Comment: @dfeuer I think that "lack of context" is not enough reason to close this specific question, which is interesting *per se*.

Comment: OK, James, you've been warned: your problem lacks context. That means people want to know where it comes from, and why you are interested in it (and they'll close it if you don't tell them).

Comment: @dfeuer: It’s its own context: it’s inherently interesting.

Comment: @dfeuer: No, the community has not. A significant number of people in the community have done so; I don’t know what propertion it comprises, but there are quite a few of us who disagree. And let’s be honest: it doesn’t take all that many to screw up the works for those of us who don’t agree.

Comment: Generally, stating a question and not showing what you have tried to solve it nor where the problem came from will end up in some close votes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following might need a few details filled in, so view it as a hint.

The rectangle $R=[0,m] \times [0,n]$ has $mn$ lattice points in it with positive coordinates. The line $L: y=tx$ does not pass through any of these lattice points since $t$ is irrational. The first sum counts the lattice points below $L$, and the second counts lattice points above $L$, since a point above $L$ is also to the left of $L$ and $L$ may also be written as $x=y/t$

Note: one detail is that from $n=\left \lfloor{mt}\right \rfloor$ we have the highest lattice point of the form $(m,k)$ is the upper right corner $(m,n)$
--actually the important feature is that the largest thing counted in the first sum is this upper right point in the rectangular lattice $R.$ Then the line $L$ cuts through the top edge of $R$ in such a way that nothing counted in the two sums happens to lie outside the rectangle.

Comment: How did you jump from those crazy sums to such a simple geometrical characterization?

Comment: @dfeuer There's a similar use of breaking up a rectangular lattice into points above and below a line in one proof I saw of quadratic reciprocity. That reminded me of this question.

Comment: Very nice. ${}$

Comment: Apologies for the lack of context. I saw this question in a past exam paper and couldn't think how to go about it. I would like to thank coffeemath for his very nice idea

Comment: @Jamesmacleod The best way to thank coffeemath for his idea is by choosing his answer!